# Infinite print list function

Tags: c++, list, printing, infinite

I am implementing a linked list class in C++, and my print function keeps printing forever. I am wondering if my insert function is turning my linked list into a circular linked list, that would explain why my print function keeps going around in circles and printing the list over and over.

Please help me figure out why!

Here is my Node defintition in my LList.h file:

```
struct Node {
    char info;
    Node *next;
};
```

Here is my insert and cons function in my LList.cpp file:

```
Node *LList::cons(char ch, Node *p) {
        Node *q = new Node;
        q->info = ch;
        q->next = p;
        return q;
    }
________________________________________________
Node *LList::insert(char ch, Node *p) {
        if (p == nullptr || ch <= p->info) {
            return cons(ch,p);
        }
        Node *q = p;
        Node *r = q->next;

        while (r != nullptr && ch > r->info) {
            q=r;
            r=r->next;
    }
        q->next = cons(ch,p);
        return p;
    }
```

And here is my print function in my LList.cpp file:

```
void LList::print (Node *head) const{
    Node *p = head;
        while (p != nullptr) {
            std::cout << p->info << " ";
            p = p->next;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The naming here is problematic. What does `cons` supposed to do? We can see from the code what it does, but if it's wrong, how can we know what it should do in order to make suggestions? What are `q` and `p`, and `r` supposed to represent?

Comment: Why you're passing a `Node *p` to the `insert` method of a class `LList`, which should already be touting its own `head` pointer for managing its linked list internally, is somewhat mysterious. Likewise with `print`, which should just reference the `LList`'s `head`. This almost looks like someone took a C-based linked list implementation and stuffed it into a `LList` class, keeping all function signatures as-is/was.

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor sets next to the current item, so next never points to nullptr.  As a result, next is never null.  Modify your constructor and I think you'll be close to behaving.